# Passing objects nested in array as function parameter string

Tags: php

I want to measure the time for a certain encoding task in PHP. I wrote the following code to measure time.

```
<?php

    class encode_logs_vo {
        public $id_host, $id_vhost, $id_contents, $serverid;
        public function __construct($id_host, $id_vhost, $id_contents, $serverid) {
            $this->id_host = $id_host;
            $this->id_vhost = $id_vhost;
            $this->id_contents = $id_contents;
            $this->serverid = $serverid;
        }
    }

    class encode_logs {

        private $start_microtime = 0;

        public function __construct(encode_logs_vo $encode_logs_vo) {
            $this->encode_logs_vo = $encode_logs_vo;
        }

        public function start_measuring() {
            MDB::execute(encode_logs_sql::insert($this->encode_logs_vo->id_host, $this->encode_logs_vo->id_vhost, $this->encode_logs_vo->id_contents, $this->encode_logs_vo->serverid));
            $this->start_microtime = microtime(true);
        }

        public function stop_measuring() {
            MDB::execute(encode_logs_sql::update($this->encode_logs_vo->id_host, $this->encode_logs_vo->id_vhost, $this->encode_logs_vo->id_contents, $this->encode_logs_vo->serverid, microtime(true) - $this->start_microtime));
            $this->start_microtime = 0;
        }

        public function update_measuring($exec_time) {
            MDB::execute(encode_logs_sql::update($this->encode_logs_vo->id_host, $this->encode_logs_vo->id_vhost, $this->encode_logs_vo->id_contents, $this->encode_logs_vo->serverid, $exec_time));
        }

        public static function clear($interval_month) {
            MDB::execute(encode_logs_sql::delete($interval_month));
        }
    }

    class encode_logs_sql {

        static function insert($id_host, $id_vhost, $id_contents, $serverid) {
            $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $sql = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO
        encode_logs(
            id_host, id_vhost, id_contents, serverid, create_date
        ) VALUES (
            {$id_host}, {$id_vhost}, {$id_contents}, '{$serverid}', '{$now}'
        ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            update_date = '{$now}'
SQL;
            return $sql;
        }

        static function update($id_host, $id_vhost, $id_contents, $serverid, $exec_time) {
            $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $sql = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO
        encode_logs(
            id_host, id_vhost, id_contents, serverid, exec_time, create_date
        ) VALUES (
            {$id_host}, {$id_vhost}, {$id_contents}, '{$serverid}', '{$exec_time}', '{$now}'
        ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            exec_time = exec_time + '{$exec_time}'
SQL;
            return $sql;
        }

        static function delete($interval_month) {
            $interval_month = -1 * $interval_month;
            $sql = <<<SQL
DELETE
FROM
    encode_logs
WHERE
    update_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL {$interval_month} MONTH)
SQL;
            return $sql;
        }

    }
```

I use the code in the following manner

```
$encode_logs = new encode_logs(new encode_logs_vo($id_host, $id_vhost, $id_contents, $serverid="some server"));
$encode_logs->start_measuring();

    //do Some task
$encode_logs->stop_measuring();
```

The above works very well if all of this is located in the same file.
Now I want to start measuring time from one function and stop measuring in another function. So, I tried this:

```
function one(){

$encode_logs = new encode_logs(new encode_logs_vo($id_host, $id_vhost, $id_contents, $serverid="some server"));
$encode_logs->start_measuring();
$data = array(
            "param1" => "something",
            "encode_logs" => $encode_logs
        );
two(json_encode($data));
}

function two($data){
//do something
$data = json_decode($data);
$param1 = $data->param1;
$encode_logs = $data->encode_logs
$encode_logs->stop_measuring(); //error at this point

}
```

I tried to typecast in `function two`, but it still gives the following error on stop measuring.

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::stop_measuring()
```

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::stop_measuring()

Comment: Can you confirm that there is not some code that you are missing from your description? In the code that you included, `one()` clearly creates a new `encode_logs`, and passes that to `two()`, which uses it immediately. So there really should be no way to wind up with a `stdClass` instead of an `encode_logs`.

Comment: sorry, I changed function one and two now.

Comment: In your revised code, you pass `two()` an array, but you attempt to access it as an object. This will not work. You need to access it as `$data['param1']` and `$data['encode_logs']`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Now, if you want to pass the object as a string, I tried to encode it in JSON format and then decode it and then access the object (modified function one and two again! sorry). It doesn't work then?

Comment: Why are you trying to json_encode/json_decode it? That's entirely unnecessary, and the round-trip causes the `encode_logs` to turn into a separate instance of `stdClass`. JSON does not have the concept of different object types, and even if it did, the conversion results in a *different* object instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100201/discussion-between-user3288346-and-jbafford).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the chat, what's actually happening is that between `one()` and `two()` is a round-trip through `json_encode`/`json_decode` and a message queue that expects content as a string.

This means that the original object instance in `one()` no longer exists in `two()`, which has a number of implications:

- JSON does not have the concept of class types, so at a minimum, the round-trip through the JSON encoder loses the class type information.
- Even if class type information were retained, the resulting object after decode would be a separate instance. In this particular case, that shouldn't be a problem, but it's entirely possible for the encode/decode to be lossy, as not all information that can be represented in a PHP object can be serialized into a JSON string.

One alternative is to use [serialize](http://www.php.net/serialize) and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). By using a php-native serialization method, the class information can be persisted. Care must still be taken, because this can also be lossy, but more information can be retained; in particular, associative arrays will remain as such rather than being converted to objects as with the JSON functions.